# How to use "keep_environment" option in exim 4 on Debian

Tags: debian, cron, exim

I am running exim 4.84_2 on Debian, now since a few weeks I get the following mails from anacron:

```
/etc/cron.daily/exim4-base:
LOG: MAIN
  Warning: purging the environment.
 Suggested action: use keep_environment.
```

I have added the following line to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`:

```
keep_environment =
```

But when running `update-exim4.conf` I get the following error:

```
2016-05-17 00:20:00 Exim configuration error in line 900 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  option "keep_environment" unknown
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep the environment purged, that is a security fix. Further reading can be found here https://www.exim.org/static/doc/CVE-2016-1531.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian you can set the macro

```
MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT =
```

in /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs or where ever you set your macros. See: /usr/share/doc/exim4/changelog.Debian.gz

Comment: I activated a new server with VestaCP, but we got this error too (I have made some VPS+Vesta, but it's the first occurence with this error). I should just past this code into 01... file without any value after = sign? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, without anything.

Comment: If you are not using a split-file configuration, you can add set this macro at the top of `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`

Comment: It's generally better to add such things to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`. Works for split and non-split configs.

Comment: And if you're running Jessie, `MAIN_KEEP_ENVIRONMENT` won't help. It was added later. In case of Debian Stretch, you don't have to do anything. Save probably update `exim`.

Answer (score 0):

Do note the comments in exim4.conf.template and /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs:

```
# /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template is only used with the non-split
#   configuration scheme.
# /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/01_exim4-config_listmacrosdefs is only used
#   with the split configuration scheme.
```

In other words, the file to edit may vary depending on whether you're using split configuration files.

I followed the configuration example in the link below and it worked:

https://tronche.com/wiki/Exim_keep_environment

Answer (score 0):

If you get `option "keep_environment" unknown`, then most likely your `exim` doesn't have a certain [security fix](https://www.exim.org/static/doc/CVE-2016-1531.txt).

The fix was made in `4.86.2`. But also backported to `4.84.2`. Both [Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/exim4) and [Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/exim4) have it. It cleans the environment according to `keep_environment`, `add_environment` options. If `keep_environment` is not set, it logs a warning and suggests to add it. Since `exim` might be configured in a way that needs to keep some environment variables. Which is not the case on Debian with the default config. So on Debian normally it can be set to empty value.

And at some [point](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/blob/09_stretch/debian/debconf/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options#L210-215) the option was [added](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/commit/5fbee94e) to the [config](https://salsa.debian.org/exim-team/exim4/commit/27427b46) (`4.87--RC6-3`). But it was in Debian Stretch. That's unlikely to be backpoirted to Jessie, since it is no security issue.

So, update `exim`. Then if you're running Jessie, add to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`:

```
keep_environment =
```

And:

```
update-exim4.conf
systemctl reload exim4
```